# AWS Session Manager connection status dependent on instance state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

does the ec2 instance need to be running? or is it all dependent on if ssm manager agent is running?

i have an instance that has it running with instance is started, when i stop the instance and send a command, i get an error about ssm, so I am assuming that the machine must run for ssm to be considered connected?

Comment: The Systems Manager agent is a piece of software that runs on your instance, inside the Operating System. This is just like an FTP server or a web server -- it is software running inside the instance itself. Therefore, the instance must be ON and the operating system must be running for the Agent to be running.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the SSM agent?

Answer (score 0):

> does the ec2 instance need to be running?

Yes.

> is it all dependent on if ssm manager agent is running?

Yes. SSM agent will not run if instance is stopped.